# SavingsAccount constructor

Tags: java, constructor

If I have class name SavingsAccount, two instance variables such as private double balance and private double
Interest then how do I code a constructor that has initialBalance and interest?

Comment: add your code, so we know what your thinking

Comment: It's never too early to form good habits.  Don't use `double` for currency.  Use an integer-like type and count the smallest denomination (e.g., for US currency, store the balance as a number of pennies.)

Comment: @jameslarge A fair comment and definitely worth noting - however this reads like it's an academic exercise, so they've probably been mandated to use a double in this instance.

Comment: Yes in the book so far it only shows using double so far.

Comment: OK, so do what the instrutor says, but be aware that the double data type has no exact representation of 0.01 or, of many other fractional numbers.  The result of every double computation is rounded to the nearest number that a double _can_ represent.  In the real world, if the software ends up giving one penny to the wrong party because of rounding, and if it does it millions or billions of times; then there will be lawsuits, accusations of massive fraud, possible prison time for people who should have known, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SavingsAccount {

private double balance;
private double interest;

public SavingsAccount(double balance, double interest) {
this.balance = balance;
this.interest = interest;
}
}
```

Comment: This looks about right! But I believe I have tried this already and it was throwing errors on the commas? And it says I need to use initialBalance and Interest.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
public SavingsAccount(double balance, double interest) {
    this.balance = balance;
    this.interest = interest;
}

public SavingsAccount() {
    this(0d, 1d); // default is 0 for balance, 1 for interest rate
}
```

Comment: Primitive data type are initialized to their default values, no need to set it explicitly.

Comment: Yes, my example isn't that helpful in that regard, but maybe he wants different defaults, I'll edit it

Comment: What do you mean by primitive data types, no need for explicit setting?

Comment: Primitive datatypes are not objects based on a class. They exist within the framework. You don't need to import java.lang.Integer everytime you want to use an int. Also, their values are stored entirely in memory. So if you say `int i = 3` the following bits will be stored in memory: `..bunch of zeros..011`. Primitive datatypes have a default value. If you do `int i` (without assigning it some value), it will have the value 0 (it will not be null like an object). Likewise, doubles are set to 0.0, etc..